# Tabla con consecutivo y acumulador en Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tablas

En esta tabla programada en VUE 2 quiero este resultado:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| fact    $importe  $ acumula  consecutivo  |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 23       $ 350     $ 350           1      |
| 28       $ 200     $ 550           2      |
| 32       $ 300     $ 850           3      |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

este es mi código actual:

```
<tr v-for="movi in movimientos">
 <td>{{movi.factura}}</td>
 <td>{{movi.importe}}{{acumular(movi.importe)}}</td>
 <td> {{saldo}} </td>
</tr>
```

¿Cómo le hago para obtener el acumulado y el consecutivo en vue ?

```
mounted(){
        this.entrar();
    },
    data(){
        return{
            movimientos: null,
            saldo: 0
        }
        },
    methods:{
       entrar(){
            axios.get('miservidor/lee.php?idc='+this.id)
                 .then((respues) => {
                    this.movimientos = respues.data;
            });
       },
       acumular(importe){
           this.saldo = this.saldo + importe;
       }
    }
```

Comment: nos muestras que código llevas a´si como las dudas claras que tienes?

Comment: puedes mostrar el código javascript? Por ejemplo que datos hay en movimientos?

Comment: en movimientos solo tiene el campo factura y el campo importe. Los otros dos campos (el acumulador y el consecutivos) se deben generar del campo importe y un simple consecutivo. No sé como generar estos dos campos

Comment: Es decir `movimientos` esta dentro de `data`, cierto? algo como   `data: {
    movimientos: {factura:23, importe: 350}
  }`

Comment: me dice en la consola: "You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a hacer algunos supuestos sobre tus datos, pero esta idea te puede funcionar:

**Template**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>factura</th>
    <th>importe</th>
    <th>acumula</th> 
    <th>consecutivo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(mov, indice) in newMovimientos">
    <td>{{mov.factura}}</td>
    <td>{{mov.importe}}</td>
    <td>{{mov.acum}}</td>
    <td>{{indice + 1}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
  data: {
    // asumo que así se ven tus datos por el ejemplo que muestras
    movimientos: [
    {factura: 23, importe: 350},
    {factura: 28, importe: 200},
    {factura: 32, importe: 300}
    ]
  },

  computed: {
     newMovimientos() {
       const newArray = this.movimientos.map(a => ({...a})) // crea una copia de movimientos
       let acum = 0
       newArray.forEach(p => {
         acum += p.importe
         p.acum = acum // agrego esta propiedad para guardar el acumulado
       })
       return newArray
     }
  }
```

La idea es que crees una copia del array `movimientos`, y en esta copia agregues una propiedad `acum` donde se acumulen los importes.

Este array lo montas en una computed property llamada `newMovimientos`, y esta es la que vas a iterar en el `v-for`.

Comment: Excelente Javier, esta es la respuesta correcta. Mil gracias, eres el Master